# MEAN stack Angular shows Object from Express but not HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, mean

I am trying to make a Blog site and I am stuck at creating single 'post' view page. When I got /post/id page from href everything works but when I refresh the page manually or share the link I get page like this:

```
{"_id":"56fa7443c1542bdc3bdb3857","user":{"_id":"56fa6b0cc83017643c50c5ad",
```

Been stuck at this for days, how can I fix this?

Express code (./app/backend/routes/post.js)

```
router.get('/:id', function (req, res) {
    Model.findById(req.params.id, function(err, post){
        return res.status(200).send(post);
    })
    .populate('user');
});
```

Angular PostCtrl code (./app/frontend/js/controller/post.js)

```
$http.get('/post/'+$routeParams.id).success(function (post) {
    post.text = $sce.trustAsHtml(post.text);
    $scope.post = post;

}).error(function (error, status) {
    $scope.errorMessage = error + ' (code:' + status + ')';
});
```

Routes (./app/frontend/js/app.js)

```
$routeProvider
.when('/', {
  templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
  controller: 'MainCtrl'
})
.when('/post/:id', {
  templateUrl: 'views/post.html',
  controller: 'PostCtrl'
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it fixed. I had to change Angular routing from `.when('/post/:id'` to `.when('/blog/:id'` and change the hrefs to `/blog/:id`.

It seems angular and express routing cant be the same. Express seems to still send the data to `/post/:id` and angular gets the data from there and displays it to `/blog/:id` now. After refreshing the page everything seems to work fine now. Just need to hide sensitive data in `/post/:id` now or find a way users can get access to `/post/:id`.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to understand your code and this is what I could come up with

```
// this is how the route should be using populate
router.get('/post/:id', function (req, res) {
  Model.findOne({_id: req.params.id}).populate('user').exec(function (error, post) { 
    if (post) {
      res.status(200).json(post);
    } else {  
      // handle error here...
    }
  })
});
```

Every other thing looks okay.

I hope this helps.

Comment: On refresh it now keeps showing HTML but.. now for some unknown reason the data in $scope.post is text of index.html instead of a certain post. Dont know how that happened.

Comment: What exactly is `post.text = $sce.trustAsHtml(post.text)` doing? Note that you are modifying the object before assigning it to `$scope.post`. Try commenting that line out and see what happens.

Comment: Express wont send data for single post. I got it to send the data `router.get('/:id', function (req, res) {` with this but still when I refresh the page I get the Object data printed to the page and no html at all. Here is a picture of what I get when I refesh the page http://puu.sh/nYvWI/6bc96f911c.png

Comment: `post.text = $sce.trustAsHtml(post.text)` this makes it so that saved blog post can be seen on the page as HTML with included html tags and so on.   Blog post text is saved as raw html.

Comment: I see no reason why express shouldn't send data for single post. It should be something wrong with the API or the way you are fetching the data with angular. When you refresh the page, which part of the controller gets called first? Then, maybe you can use `ng-if` to delay the display of the single post until express has return the data and you can toggle the flag after the this line `post.text = $sce.trustAsHtml(post.text)` and `$scope.post = post`. Maybe you can provide screenshots of when the page loads correctly and when it does not after refreshing.

Comment: http://puu.sh/nYxgb/db543badf3.png This is how it should work this is again with `router.get('/:id', function (req, res) {` line. This is when I refresh the page http://puu.sh/nYxBr/2f8c069818.png . Controller code `$http.get('/post/'+$routeParams.id).success(function (post) {
        console.log('ANgular - PostCtrl - SinglePost');
        $scope.post = $sce.trustAsHtml(post.text);
        $scope.post = post;
        console.log(post);         
    });`

Comment: There is an error in this part of the code you just posted: `$scope.post = $sce.trustAsHtml(post.text); $scope.post = post;`. You first assigned `$scope.post` to the result of calling `trustAsHtml` on post.text that you got from the backend. Then, you are reassigning the same `$scope.post` to post.

Comment: I removed the $scope.post and made it so that it would print out the post from backend. This is what I get in the console: http://puu.sh/nZ8kT/e57311c6a0.png . http://puu.sh/nZ8wj/3bcc981d7b.png